# Export data from sql server to excel using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005, export-to-excel, ssis

First I will explain what is my requirement and then I will explain what I have done so far and what are all the helps I need...

I have to export data from sql server to excel sheet. The excel sheet will be like a standard **template**. If I run my project, the data from SQL Server should be inserted into a new excel file which should use that template and it should be **created and saved** into a new location. Also, generally we will use first row as header. But in my requirement, the template will have **two or three rows header**. So, the data should be inserted automatically from the third/fourth empty row.

I have done exporting data from sql server database to normal excel sheet with first row as header. I have also done exporting data from different tables into different sheets of the same excel file.

Any body please help out for the template format, creation of new excel file while running project and two or three rows as header.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2005.

Please help out...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If your export is to Excel 2007 or 2010 can you use [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to handle the Excel-files.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx).

Create your report how it has to look like.
Then deploy it on a reporting server web.
Then create a subscription where you export the report to a excel file. You can setup location and time it has to run.
THe report can look like however you need it.